# Writing chrome extension to control serial port

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension (not chrome app) to control serial port but chrome extension doesnt provide any api to access it.
Because chrome doesnt give permission to direct access the port, I thought I can write C code that control the serial port and then I use this C code in the extension. I found several method to use C codes in the chrome extension. These are;

- Pepper api
- Emscripten
- Native communication

I dont want to use native communication because it requires third party apps.

Emscripten is a tool that convert c code to javascript code. But I cant access the serial port on windows because it doesnt support platform-specific code such as "Windows.h"

Pepper api is part of the chrome development tools but I cant see any api that can access the serial port. Maybe I miss something that can be useful.

Are there any way to control serial port in the chrome extension without using third party app or using chrome app.

Comment: emscripten won't work, as that compiles your code to javascript, and you therefore have all the limitations of the javascript sandbox.

Comment: Why can't you use Chrome Apps? You will be able to use [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) to run them on Linux/Windows/Mac after native Chrome support is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [chrome.runtime.connect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) API to connect your chrome extension to a chrome app. You can then have the chrome app do the serial work, while still being able to access the interface (or whatever your plans are with the chrome extension) in that chrome extension.

This does require both the chrome extension and the chrome app to be installed but it does achieve your goal.